# List all possible microstates and corresponding energy using mathematica.

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

Consider 10 identical indistinguishable particles placed on 3 energy states with energy mgh, 2mgh,3mgh respectively.List all possible microstates and corresponding energies.

I am a physics student and I am new to mathematica. I know there will be total 66   microstates. But I am not able to generate the list of microstates and corrosponding energies in mathematica.

Comment: you have the equation for number of microstates, yes?

Comment: One approach is to use the `Table` command and the `Flatten` command to generate a list of all possible triples, {0,0,0}, ... {2,3,5}, ... {7,7,7} ... etc.  Then you can `Select` the ones that have a `Total` of 10 particles.  Edit your question to show us your code and tell us where you are stuck.  Also, it will be simpler if you start with only a few particles.  There are other commands that can do the same thing, but `Table`, `Flatten` and `Select` are very basic commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is, in combinatorics, called [weak composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)). In *Mathematica* weak compositions can be generated by taking [`Permutations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations.html) of [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html).

```
states = Join @@ Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[10, {3}, Range[0, 10]]
(* {{10, 0, 0}, {0, 10, 0}, {0, 0, 10}, {9, 1, 0}, {9, 0, 1}, {1, 9, 0}, {1, 0, 9}, {0, 9, 1}, {0, 1, 9}, {8, 2, 0}, {8, 0, 2}, {2, 8, 0}, {2, 0, 8}, {0, 8, 2}, {0, 2, 8}, {8, 1, 1}, {1, 8, 1}, {1, 1, 8}, {7, 3, 0}, {7, 0, 3}, {3, 7, 0}, {3, 0, 7}, {0, 7, 3}, {0, 3, 7}, {7, 2, 1}, {7, 1, 2}, {2, 7, 1}, {2, 1, 7}, {1, 7, 2}, {1, 2, 7}, {6, 4, 0}, {6, 0, 4}, {4, 6, 0}, {4, 0, 6}, {0, 6, 4}, {0, 4, 6}, {6, 3, 1}, {6, 1, 3}, {3, 6, 1}, {3, 1, 6}, {1, 6, 3}, {1, 3, 6}, {6, 2, 2}, {2, 6, 2}, {2, 2, 6}, {5, 5, 0}, {5, 0, 5}, {0, 5, 5}, {5, 4, 1}, {5, 1, 4}, {4, 5, 1}, {4, 1, 5}, {1, 5, 4}, {1, 4, 5}, {5, 3, 2}, {5, 2, 3}, {3, 5, 2}, {3, 2, 5}, {2, 5, 3}, {2, 3, 5}, {4, 4, 2}, {4, 2, 4}, {2, 4, 4}, {4, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 3}, {3, 3, 4}} *)
states // Length
(* 66 *)
```

Indeed there are 66 of them. Number of weak `k`-compositions of `n` can be also calculated using `Binomial[n + k - 1, n]`:

```
Binomial[10 + 3 - 1, 10]
(* 66 *)
```

If we put energies of subsequent energy states in a `List`, then energy of a state of your 10-particle system can be calculated using [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) function. Below we group states by their energy:

```
energies = {1, 2, 3};
KeySort@GroupBy[states, energies.# &]
(* <|10 -> {{10, 0, 0}},
     11 -> {{9, 1, 0}},
     12 -> {{9, 0, 1}, {8, 2, 0}},
     13 -> {{8, 1, 1}, {7, 3, 0}},
     14 -> {{8, 0, 2}, {7, 2, 1}, {6, 4, 0}},
     15 -> {{7, 1, 2}, {6, 3, 1}, {5, 5, 0}},
     16 -> {{7, 0, 3}, {4, 6, 0}, {6, 2, 2}, {5, 4, 1}},
     17 -> {{3, 7, 0}, {6, 1, 3}, {4, 5, 1}, {5, 3, 2}},
     18 -> {{2, 8, 0}, {6, 0, 4}, {3, 6, 1}, {5, 2, 3}, {4, 4, 2}},
     19 -> {{1, 9, 0}, {2, 7, 1}, {5, 1, 4}, {3, 5, 2}, {4, 3, 3}},
     20 -> {{0, 10, 0}, {1, 8, 1}, {2, 6, 2}, {5, 0, 5}, {4, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 3}},
     21 -> {{0, 9, 1}, {1, 7, 2}, {4, 1, 5}, {2, 5, 3}, {3, 3, 4}},
     22 -> {{0, 8, 2}, {4, 0, 6}, {1, 6, 3}, {3, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 4}},
     23 -> {{0, 7, 3}, {3, 1, 6}, {1, 5, 4}, {2, 3, 5}},
     24 -> {{3, 0, 7}, {0, 6, 4}, {2, 2, 6}, {1, 4, 5}},
     25 -> {{2, 1, 7}, {1, 3, 6}, {0, 5, 5}},
     26 -> {{2, 0, 8}, {1, 2, 7}, {0, 4, 6}},
     27 -> {{1, 1, 8}, {0, 3, 7}},
     28 -> {{1, 0, 9}, {0, 2, 8}},
     29 -> {{0, 1, 9}},
     30 -> {{0, 0, 10}}|> *)
```